# Symmetry and periodicity of ODEs solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, symmetry

Consider a set of smooth ODE:
$$(1)~~~~~~~~~\dot{x} = f(x)$$
with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider also a linear transformaton $\gamma : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. We say that $\gamma$ is a **symmetry** if $\gamma (x(t))$ is a solution of $(1)$ when $x(t)$ is a solution, too.

<s>Suppose that $x(t)$ is a solution of $(1)$ and it is $T$-periodic. Consider also that there exists a symmetry $\gamma$ as above.</s>

Can I say that

$$\gamma (x(t)) = x(t + \tau)$$ 
?

If so, what about $\tau$?.

**Errate Corrige**

Thanks to cnick, I realized that I wrote wrongly my question. Here is the correction:

Suppose that $x(t)$ is a solution of $(1)$ and it is $T$-periodic. Can I say that there always exists a symmetry $\gamma$ such that:

$$\gamma (x(t)) = x(t + \tau)$$ 
?

If so, what about $\tau$?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your statement will not follow.
Consider the ODE:
$$
x^{\prime} = -y\\
y^{\prime} = x
$$
The solution will be a family of circles around the origin.
By the definitions provided, $\gamma(x,y) = 2(x,y)$ will be a symmetry.  But since $\gamma(x(t_1)) \neq x(t_2)$ for any values of $t_1$ or $t_2$ since $\gamma$ is a dilation of the original solution.

Comment: Maybe I write wrongly my question. Indeed, there can be many symmetries for $f(x)$. But consider $$\gamma(x,y) = (-y, x)$$ and $x(0)=1$ and $y(0)=0$. Then, you got a phase-shift, right?